# How to use BufferedReader correctly with sockets

Tags: java, android, sockets, chat, bufferedreader

The application is a **basic chat client.**
I got a **Thread** for getting data from the server.

I want to get every response from the server **separately**.
It prints in the console only when the loop breaks (when i send "exit" using the other parts of the application).
So when "System.out.println" responds **it prints the whole buffer at once.**

How can i make it work and print every response separately?

Thank you!

**EDIT!!**

The server respond should **include "\n" after each line**,

it works for me in this way.

Without "\n" it just waits until the loop breaks.

Is there a better way to do this without the "\n" issue?

```
    class ServerThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run(){
        BufferedReader in = null;
        Socket socket;
        try
        {
            if (Thread.currentThread().isAlive()) {
                sendString("exit");
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();}

            InetAddress serverAddress = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddress, SERVER_PORT);
            outr = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            String serverResponse;
            while((serverResponse = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(serverResponse);
            }

            in.close();
            outr.close();
            socket.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use `close()` in `finally` block

Comment: In your server code you probably don't add a line separator at the end of each response and all the responses add up to a single line.

Comment: @Titus The server responds after each msg, when i check it with python server it works without problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a `BufferedReader` and read it with `in.readLine()`, which, surprise surprise, will return the next *line* in the response. A *line* is a string terminated by a newline character, so your `BufferedReader` will have to wait until it sees a newline until it can return your line. If you don't want to use newlines in your response, don't use `readLine()`, use one of the other `read()` methods instead.

Comment: Thanks, don't know how I did not think of newline character before.